# Vue3/Vuex - Where am I "mutating vuex store state outside mutation handlers"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When calling a Vuex *Action* where Firebase successfully updates, followed by a *Vuex Mutation* on `state.profile`, Vue triggers the following errors upon `save` within `watch()`.

`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback`

`Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

I have cloned and then merged `store.state.profile` into `formData` via *rfdc*.

Form values are updated within it's own `reactive()` data object `formData`, versus immediately committing to store in order to later provide both `save()` and `cancel()` options.

**template**

```
<template>
    <element-textarea
        id="about"
        title="About"
        :rows="10"
        v-model="about"
    ></element-textarea>
    <element-checkbox
        v-for="(specialty, i) in jSpecialties"
        :key="i"
        :id="specialty.toLowerCase()"
        :title="specialty"
        v-model="specialties[specialty]"
    >
        {{ specialty }}
    </element-checkbox>
</template>
```

**script**

```js
...
const clone = require('rfdc/default')

export default defineComponent({
    ...
    setup(){
        ...
        let specialties: { [key: string]: boolean } = {}
        jSpecialties.map(name => (specialties[name] = false))
        const formData = reactive({
            about: '',
            specialties
        })

        watch(
            () => store.state.profile,
            () => {
                try {
                    Object.assign(formData, clone(store.state.profile))
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log('Error Appears Here', err)
                }
            }
        )

        const save = () =>
            store.dispatch('updateProfile', formData)
                .catch(err => console.log(err))

        return { ...toRefs(formData), save }
    }
})
```

**vuex**

```js
export default createStore({
    strict: true,
    state: {
        profile: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setProfile: (state, payload) => state.profile = payload,
    },
    actions: {
        updateProfile: ({state, commit}, data) => {
            const update = () =>
                db
                    .collection(...)
                    .doc(...)
                    .set(data, {merge: true})
                    .then(_ => commit('setProfile', data))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            return update()
        }
    }
})
```

---

When removing `strict: true` from vuex, I receive this error:

`Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.`

---

Replacing `watch()` with `watchEffect()` get rid of the *Maximum recursive updates exceeded* error.

```
watchEffect(() => {
    try {
        Object.assign(formData, clone(store.state.profile))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

However, when updating Vuex with `strict: true`, I am still receiving the following:

`Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Comment: Most likely `clone` from `rfdc` doesn't strip away the reactivity of your `store.state.profile`, `clone(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store.state.profile)))` would ensure that the reactivity is stripped

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Same result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't pass a `try..catch` block into the `watch` function's arguments (or any JS function for that matter)

Comment: @Phil The result is an additional `Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback` error. Two turns into three errors.

Comment: What I mean is that your code isn't even valid JS. It should be generating _"Uncaught SytaxError: Unexpected token 'try'"_. See https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watching-a-single-source for the correct syntax

Comment: @Phil That `try` block was a site posting error. It is corrected now.

Comment: When removing `strict: true`, I receive the following error: `Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the issue. I overlooked my copying of a reference object back to state.

I needed to clone `formData` prior to dispatching, as the same `data` object was also committed to store via actions.

```
const save = () =>
    store.dispatch('updateProfile', clone(formData))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```